# Having troubles getting my hashing algorithm to work

Tags: java, hashtable

**PROBLEM SOLVED(Can't accept answer yet, I changed my while loop and now it works, I answered it below for any future viewers):** My hashing algortihm is causing me to have a headache. I read input from a file for the keys and with a small amount of keys, my code works, once I make it like 300 words, I have issues. The hashing function is at the bottom and this while loop is in the body of my main function, it's written in java. The hashing function worked well and so did the body until I stupidly changed the body and lost original code. I think I covered overflow issues but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

How tSize is calculated:

```
//Calcking tSize
tSize = (int)(items*tSizeFactor);

//Making tSize prime
while(!isPrime((int)tSize))
    tSize++;
```

While loop for when I read from the file:

```
while(line != null) {
                //Getting the address to place the value in
                position = hash(line.toCharArray(), (int)tSize);

                //If there is something there we enter the if statement
                if(hashTable[position][0] != null) {
                    //while we haven't found a spot and i < tableSize we update the last position we were at and move through the array
                    for(int i = 1; i < (int)tSize && hashTable[position][0] != null; i++) {
                        //prevPosition is used to update the link in the spot just before our final destination, allows wrap around in the array
                        prevPosition = position;
                        //we add +i to the original position and modulo the table size allowing wrap around in the array
                        position = (position+i)%(int)tSize;
                    }
                    //finally when we found a spot we update the previous position to link to the new item
                    hashTable[prevPosition][1] = Integer.toString(position);
                }

                //Adding the values to the hash table and setting the link to -1
                hashTable[position][0] = new String(line);
                hashTable[position][1] = new String(Integer.toString(-1));

                line = reader.readLine();
            }

public static int hash(char ch[],final int TSIZE) {
        int sum = 7;
        for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            sum = sum*31+ch[i];
            sum <<= 3;
        }

        if(sum < 0)
            sum *= -1;

        return sum%TSIZE;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know 300 was a *huge* number of test cases.

Comment: Unless your file is full of words like "Lopado­temacho­selacho­galeo­kranio­leipsano­drim­hypo­trimmato­silphio­parao­melito­katakechy­meno­kichl­epi­kossypho­phatto­perister­alektryon­opte­kephallio­kigklo­peleio­lagoio­siraio­baphe­tragano­pterygon", 300 isn't that much.

Comment: "Having troubles" What troubles?

Comment: I don't like much the line `sum <<= 3;` , the multiplication in the line above already does a 5-bit shift.

Comment: You're really going to have to be more specific about the type of error you've gotten.

Comment: I kept losing a reference somewhere, I'm going to remove the second hash call, logically it makes sense that should fix my problem

Comment: The hash algorithm looks at least superficially valid.  We need to know a bit more precisely what sort of failure you're getting.

Comment: when I go through and start searching for values, since I use -1 as my default link I get an array out of bounds error, so pretty much, I'm not adding values into the table correctly so I must be screwing up a link somewhere, if I return 1 always in my hashing function then my code works fine, that's confusing to me

Comment: When i gets to table size you stop trying to find a hole.  You need to rework your for statement.

Comment: But there wouldn't be any need to go over table size right? Because with modulo I'd just start repeating previous values I already checked, if I understand the math correctly.

Comment: Maybe you're right.  But you just need to debug it.  Add println statements and trace through, to make sure it's doing what you intend.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out your "synonym chain".  It seems to me that prevPosition will always be the current position - 1, so storing the link there adds no information.

Comment: Pretty much my idea is, get the address, check to see if something exists there, if not, move to the next location, if nothing exists there, add the item and link it to other value that has the same hashed address, otherwise keep going until we find a spot and link the previous similar entry to the new one, I hope that makes sense

Comment: I understand the purpose of a synonym chain, but what good does it serve when it's just a link to the next sequential cell?  It adds no information vs just incrementing i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My changed while loop which solved the problem:

```
while(line != null) {
                    //Getting the address to place the value in
                    position = hash(line.toCharArray(), (int)tSize);

                    //If there is something there we enter the if statement
                    if(hashTable[position][0] != null) {

                        //Go to the end of the chain
                        while(hashTable[position][1].compareTo("-1") != 0)
                            position = Integer.parseInt(hashTable[position][1]);

                        //Save the position of the end of the chain
                        prevPosition = position;

                        //while we haven't found a spot and i < tableSize we update the last position we were at and move through the array
                        for(int i = 1; i < (int)tSize && hashTable[position][0] != null; i++) {
                            //we add +i to the original position and modulo the table size allowing wrap around in the array
                            position = (position+i)%(int)tSize;
                            System.out.println("Position: " + position);
                        }

                        //finally when we found a spot we update the previous position to link to the new item
                        hashTable[prevPosition][1] = Integer.toString(position);
                    }

                    //Adding the values to the hash table and setting the link to -1
                    hashTable[position][0] = new String(line);
                    hashTable[position][1] = new String(Integer.toString(-1));

                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. new String(line) is useless.
2. for(int i = 1; i < (int)tSize && hashTable[position][0] != null; i++)

   position 0 is not used?
3. prevPosition can be local to `if(hashTable[position][0] != null) {` block.
4. storing Prev position into hashtable looks useless.

   **UPD**
5. position = (position+i)%(int)tSize;

Try this one
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing

Comment: I think you misunderstand what's going on with your item 3.  A new line has been selected in the outer loop, so a new hash needs to be computed.  "position" is simply that new hash value, modulo table size.

Comment: Re item 2, presumably the intent is to create a chain of hash synonyms that the look-up routine can use.

Answer (score 0):

First, one question, why not use the build-in hashtable?

by reading your codes, I found a couple of problems. They may not correct, because some more information cannot be known from your current code. e.g. the `tSize`.

- you have a `tSize`, I think it is the capacity of the hashtable. but I didn't see when you increase it. This would be problem, well, at least performance problem. but in your implmentation, it is functional problem. for example, if your tSize is 100. then you can have max 100 elements in your hashtable.
- take a look this for loop:

  ```
  for(int i = 1; i < (int)tSize && hashTable[position][0] != null; i++) {
      prevPosition = position;
      position = (hash(line.toCharArray(), (int)tSize)+i)%((int)tSize);
  }
  ```

this will be executed when collision occurs.(I didn't understand, why you call the hash function again. you can just loop to find a free slot.)  You want to keep the original `key`, and let it reference a free position. However if in worse case, after your calling hash function again, the new `position` is still occupied (collision again), you overwrite the `prePosition` so that you lost the original `key`. This would be problem when you get data from the hashtable.

- due to above two points. when your hashtable is full, your code is just keep overwriting the last element.